# Alguém conhece alguma forma de preencher os valores nulos da tabela em anexo sem ser através de CURSOR (laço SQLSERVER)?

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, sql-server, sql-update

Preciso preencher os valores que estão nulos com os valores imediatamente acima, exemplo do dia 02 ao dia 06 tem que preencher com 100, do dia 08 ao 10 com 125, e assim por diante.
Fiz com CURSOR mas como tem muitos registros acaba ficando lento.

[image: Tabela com dados em alguns registros e que preciso preencher os valores nulos]

Comment: Se quer atualizar ou só trazer no select ? O select seria só select data,valor from tabela ?

Comment: Quero atualizar, a tabela tem outros campos irrelevantes, mas se conseguir preencher a tabela do exemplo ta show!

Comment: A saida seria um subselect ou uma analytic function , lead,lag etc , talvez o Cursor seja mais "barato" mesmo.

Comment: Qual a versão do SQL Server?

Comment: A versão é SQLSERVER 2016.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode executar um `UPDATE` com uma `subquery` para obter a última ocorrência com a coluna `valor` preenchida:

```
UPDATE t1
   SET t1.valor = (SELECT TOP 1 t2.valor
                     FROM tabela t2
                     WHERE t2.dataCalendario < t1.dataCalendario
                       AND t2.valor IS NOT NULL
                     ORDER BY t2.dataCalendario DESC)
  FROM tabela t1
 WHERE t1.valor IS NULL;
```

Veja a `query` acima funcionando no [**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=1b1b3c8496889526403a9f228ed42ba3).

Comment: Muito obrigado mano! vlw demais!!!